# How to telnet to a computer which is sharing a single public ip?

Tags: ip

Suppose that I am sharing a public ip 56.162.XXX.XXX with some other users. Now I have a local ip that I see if I type ipconfig in the command prompt. That is 192.168.2.3. Now I have a program running on port 3630 listening to any incoming connection. I can call myself with the help of loop back ip ie. telnet 127.0.0.1 3630, and i see that two programs are getting connected and can exchange data. I can also telnet and get connected with my laptop from another laptop which is sharing same public ip as mine by the command telnet 192.168.4.20 3630. But how should I do the same from a remote computer? I mean a computer which has a different public ip.
Actually I want something like "**telnet public ip(local ip) port no**". The other computer is also sharing a public ip with some other users.

Comment: What kind of device is firewalling you from the 56.162.xxx.xxx subnet

Answer (score 2):

The way you should do it is to create a port forward in your router/firewall, to forward connections on port 3630 to your local IP (which you make static). Then you can `telnet <public ip> 3630` and get access to the computer on the LAN subnet.